# Elements of the argument "group" in matplotlib.rc()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I came across this code that changes plot configuration:

```
from matplotlib import cycler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Customise configuration
colors = cycler('color',['#EE6666', '#3388BB', '#9988DD',
                         '#EECC55', '#88BB44', '#FFBBBB'])
plt.rc('axes', facecolor='#E6E6E6', edgecolor='none',
       axisbelow=True, grid=True, prop_cycle=colors)
plt.rc('grid', color='w', linestyle='solid')
plt.rc('xtick', direction='out', color='gray')
plt.rc('ytick', direction='out', color='gray')
plt.rc('patch', ec='#E6E6E6')  # sets gray edge
plt.rc('lines', linewidth=2)

# Plot data
x = np.random.randn(1000)
plt.hist(x)
```

However, the `plt.rc('patch', ec='#E6E6E6')` seems not working as there's no gray edge of the plot displayed (please see attached image). Could someone please explain what's going on? Also, how can I find the elements of the argument *group* in `matplotlib.pyplot.rc(group, **kwargs)`? Both the [doc](https://docs.w3cub.com/matplotlib~3.0/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc/) and `plt.rc?` don't elaborate on that. I tried to google `plt.rc('patch')` but couldn't find any relevant information. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [customizing with `rcParams` page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), `patch.edgecolor` (equivalent to `patch.ec`)  is only enabled if `patch.force_edgecolor` is set to `True` (the default is `False`) **or** if the `patch` is not filled (presumably either by setting `patch.facecolor` to a transparent RGBA or to `None` but the docs do not specify). So if you want to show the grey edge in this example you’d simply do

```py
plt.rc(‘patch’, ec=‘#E6E6E6’, force_edgecolor=True)
```

As far as the `group` names go, I’m not sure if there’s a way to directly get only the group names without but you can get all the current `[key, value]` pairs from `plt.rcParams.items()` so something like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for k in plt.rcParams.items():
    print(k[0])
```

should print all the `rcParams` key values in the format `group.keyword`, i.e. `patch.edgecolor`. The [linked page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) also contains all the keys and their defaults along with some explanation in the ‘sample matplotlibrc file’.

Comment: Great, thanks @William Miller! Could you please tell me how you managed to find that answer in the customizing with `rcParams` page? I think I did go through that page before posting the question but I didn't see the information on `patch` and `edgecolor` (probably I didn't read it slowly and carefully enough) so I'm very curious to learn how you did it, that is, you used brute force (reading everything on the page), or searched for keywords (patch, edgecolor)?

Comment: @Nemo I have some familiarity with customizing via `rcParams` which led me to know that the sample matplotlibrc file in the docs outlines the usage of all the keys so I kinda knew where to look.